# Audio streaming protocol for StreamTheWorld.net

Tags: audio-streaming

I am trying to download and capture audio stream from streamtheworld, and only thing I found so far is that it uses HTTP protocol and some FLV headers are visible inside.  But, it's not playable.

I would appreciate any info about it.  Transport (http), container, encoding, any info is welcome.

One example of such audio stream:

http://player.streamtheworld.com/_players/arn/index.php?callsign=VIRGINRADIO_DUBAI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply AAC over HTTP.  Nothing special.

You can find the stream URL by using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  In this case, it is:  http://4093.live.streamtheworld.com/VIRGINRADIO_DUBAIAAC

From there, you can rip using something as simple as WGET, or VLC.

---

To step you through the whole process....

**First**, the [container page](http://player.streamtheworld.com/_players/arn/index.php?callsign=VIRGINRADIO_DUBAI) loads.  That page calls the flash player with a parameter, `flashvars.callsign="VIRGINRADIO_DUBAI"`.  It undoubtedly gets this from the GET parameter in the initial container page URL.  Feel free to experiment.

**Second**, the Flash player downloads http://player.streamtheworld.com/_players/arn/coreconfig.xml.  This contains useful information.  Here is an excerpt:

```
    <zone type="liveStream">

        <liveStream>

        <!-- the endpoint node is option, and will default to the stated value if absent  -->
            <endpoint>http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream</endpoint>

        <!-- version is a mandatory value -->
        <version>1.4</version>

        <!-- Mount is a mandatory variable  -->
        <mount>KEYJFM</mount>

        <!-- The lang variable is optional, and will default to the stated value if absent  -->
        <lang>EN</lang>

        <!-- The transport variable is optional, and will default to the stated value if absent  -->
        <transport>http</transport>

        <!-- This parameter will be appended to the the mount call in the event of an HD request. -->
        <hdPostFix>AAC</hdPostFix>

        <!-- Possible values are hdConnection, normalConnection and hdAlternate -->
        <connectionType>hdAlternate</connectionType>

        </liveStream>

        <nowPlayingHistory>

        <!-- the endpoint node is option, and will default to the stated value if absent  -->
            <endpoint>http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/public/nowplaying</endpoint>

        </nowPlayingHistory>


    </zone>
```

The player also grabs http://playerwebadmin.streamtheworld.com/xmlconfig.php?view=xml&callsign=VIRGINRADIO_DUBAI&streamid=8263, which contains some meaningless crap, such as what video ad to show you.

**After the video ad**, the player grabs this:  http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream?version=1.4&mount=VIRGINRADIO_DUBAIAAC&lang=EN&transports=http&nobuf=1311628718296

Note the appropriate parameters, such as `version`, `mount`, `lang`, etc.  Recognize them?  Yes, they came from that first XML file.

**Finally**, the Flash player has all the information it needs from that final XML file to make a request to the stream.

All of this you can easily figure out with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  Please consider using it in the future.

Comment: THANKS!  Now, let's suppose that really is the case (about aac - I guess you are talking about aacplus) - now - how to find out the URL of the stream WITHOUT fiddler?  Any idea?  Winpcap?

Comment: @Daniel, you mean programmatically?  Simply parse the page.  How you do this depends on the language you are using....  and yes, that really is the case.

Comment: parse what page to get http://4093.live.streamtheworld.com/VIRGINRADIO_DUBAIAAC?  It doesn't appear on originating page.

Answer (score 8):

Get the Call Sign for the Stream. For City 101.6 Fm Dubai, its ARNCITY.

Use the following URL http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/ and replace the call sign after pls/.

So the final URl will look like http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/ARNCITY.pls

Open it in Firefox and it will ask you to download the ARNCITY.pls to your computer.

Download the file and open it in notepad and you will have the actual stream URLs.

use anyone in windows media player or any media player and you are all set..

Thats all.....Hope this helps

Comment: Wow, so they have SHOUTCAST as well :)  How did you figure that out?